# attempt to index local 'g2' (a function value)

Tags: lua

The program I'm using is called **Oxidizer**, a *fractal flam3* editor. Basically to animate these beautiful works of digital art, I am using `.lua` scripts.

The one script I'm using, `algorhythm.lua` invokes other scripts to function. One is the control script `cs_temp.lua` another is `utils.lua`. which is where I'm getting the error.

The specific line that's showing up as an error is **1399**, the second line in the following code.

```
function alignx(g1,g2)
   local x1,x2 = #g1.xforms,#g2.xforms
 -- Align xforms for final-x, pad if necessary
local fx1,fx2 = 0,0

for x=1,x1 do
      if g1.xforms[x].is_finalxform == "Y" then fx1 = x end
   end
   for x=1,x2 do
      if g2.xforms[x].is_finalxform == "Y" then fx2 = x end
   end
   if fx1>0 or fx2>0 then

  -- case 1: both have finalx - reorder g2

  if fx1>0 and fx2>0 and fx1~=fx2 then
 print('case 1')
 if fx1>x2 then              -- pad g2 with sufficient xforms
    for i=1,math.abs(fx1-x2) do 
       table.insert(g2.xforms,newx())
       print("adding xform to genome 2") 
    end
    x2 = #g2.xforms
 end
 x2ind = agen(x2,1,x2)
 x2ind[fx2] = fx1
 x2ind[fx1] = fx2
 xforms2 = ordx(g2.xforms,x2ind)
 g2.xforms = xforms2
  end

  -- case 2: g1 has finalx but not g2 - xpad and reorder g2
  if fx1>0 and fx2==0 then
 print('case 2')             -- pad g2 with final xform
 local xtmp = newx(1)
 xtmp.is_finalxform = 'Y'
 xtmp.symmetry = 1
 table.insert(g2.xforms,clone_genome(xtmp))
 print("adding final xform to genome 2") 
 x2 = #g2.xforms
 fx2 = x2
 if fx1>x2 then              -- pad g2 with sufficient xforms
    for i=1,math.abs(fx1-x2) do 
       table.insert(g2.xforms,newx())
       print("adding xform to genome 2") 
    end
    x2 = #g2.xforms
 end
 x2ind = agen(x2,1,x2)
 x2ind[fx2] = fx1
 x2ind[fx1] = fx2
 xforms2 = ordx(g2.xforms,x2ind)
 g2.xforms = xforms2
  end

  -- case 3: g2 has finalx but not g1 - xpad g1 and reorder g2
  if fx1==0 and fx2>0 then
 print('case 3')
 local xtmp = newx(1)
 xtmp.is_finalxform = 'Y'
 xtmp.symmetry = 1
 table.insert(g1.xforms,clone_genome(xtmp))
 print("adding final xform to genome 1") 
 x1 = #g1.xforms
 fx1 = x1
 if fx1>x2 then              -- pad g2 with sufficient xforms
    for i=1,math.abs(fx1-x2) do 
       table.insert(g2.xforms,newx())
       print("adding xform to genome 2") 
    end
    x2 = #g2.xforms
 end
 x2ind = agen(x2,1,x2)
 x2ind[fx2] = fx1
 x2ind[fx1] = fx2
 xforms2 = ordx(g2.xforms,x2ind)
 g2.xforms = xforms2
  end
 end
end
```

I know that's a lot to sift through but I wanted to be specific as possible.

Comment: "I know that's a lot to sift through but I wanted to be specific as possible"  [Volume is not precision.](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#volume)

Comment: You are going to have to trace back through and see what code you are calling that is ultimately calling alignx(). whatever is calling alignx() in your case, is passing a function instead of a table as the second param to alignx().

Answer (score 3):

As per your question(still unclear), the following line is the problematic one:

```
local x1,x2 = #g1.xforms,#g2.xforms
```

The error **Attempt to index** occurs in the *Lua* program because your `g2.xforms` needs to be initialised as a table, which again calls for `g2` to be a table.

Check your entire code and trace if anywhere you've defined `g2` to be function, because your program is interpreting it as a function variable instead of table.